# unable to render partial html using knockoutout component

Tags: c#, knockout.js

I have defined component like below

```
module AgeModule {

export class My_Component {
    static componentName: string = 'mycomponent';
    static templateName: string = My_Component.componentName + '-template'; 
    myObs: KnockoutObservable<any>;

    constructor(params) {

        this.myObs = params && params.myObs;

    }
    static registerComponent = () => {
        ko.components.register(My_Component.componentName, { viewModel: My_Component, template: { element: My_Component.templateName } });
    }
}
```

}

Then in cshtml i registered component like

```
  AgeModule.My_Component.registerComponent();
```

and load partial view like

```
  @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Views/Home/Partials/MyComponent.cshtml", Model)
```

Then in partial view "MyComponent.cshtml"

```
<script type="text/html" id="mycomponent-template">
   <div> KSJSDSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS</div>

 </script>
```

and i call component like

```
<mycomponent params="age: ageobs"></mycomponent>
```

i dont get any sort of errors in console but my partial view is not rendering at all. I dont know how to debug either. How to solve this?

**Update**

This works when i am binding component

```
<div data-bind="component: {name: 'mycomponent', params: {age:ageobs}}">


</div>
```

But doesnt work if u use component tag directly.

Comment: Could you please post how you initialise `My_Component` and how you apply the bindings? Where is `ageobs` coming from? Also, I don't think you need the `Model` parameter in the `@Html.Partial(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the component name must match the id in your "MyComponent.cshtml", so try either changing the `static componentName: string = 'mycomponent';` to be `editshipment-typeOfGoods` or the id to be `mycomponent-template`

Comment: i made mistake posting question. The name is correct. Please see updated question

Comment: i have setup breakpoints under typescript file but its hitting only once when component is registered but it should hit again when its called by this code 
<mycomponent params="age: ageobs"></mycomponent>